# Como armazenar resultados de cálculos estatísticos (média, correlação) para uso posterior em gráficos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[![Exemplo da Matriz de Relevância][1]][1]

Eu quero criar um gráfico que se chama tecnicamente de "Matriz de Relevância".
O conceito deste gráfico é posicionar o `KPI` (indicador de desempenho) em eixo x, este KPI é o resultado do valor de correlação `[corr()]` da métrica com a média da Satisfação Geral `[SG]`.
O código que comecei a criar está assim:

```py
    y = df['SG'].mean()
    x = df['Compra_Futura']
    z = df['Recomendação']
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=10, c='green')
    plt.scatter(z, y, s=20, c='blue')
    plt.xlabel('Grau de Importância (r)')
    plt.ylabel('Satisfação Geral (pts)')
    plt.title('Matriz de Relevância')
    plt.show()
```

Porém, está gerando erro de valor:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-099a22cf1d51> in <module>()
      4 x = df['Compra_Futura']
      5 z = df['Recomendação']
----> 6 plt.scatter(x, y, s=10, c='green')
      7 plt.scatter(z, y, s=20, c='blue')
      8 plt.xlabel('Grau de Importância (r)')
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4241         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   4242         if x.size != y.size:
-> 4243             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   4244 
   4245         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XURD.png
```

Comment: O erro fala que `x` e `y` não tem o mesmo tamanho

Comment: Bem, isto eu sei, porém como resolver o erro é o que eu espero como uma resposta adequada!

Comment: Então cara, tu quer plotar todos os elementos da coluna `compra_futura` com média da coluna `GS`, essa media vai te retornar um único elemento, equanto a outra colona todos que pertencem a ela, ai é que ta teu erro. pra corrigir isso só basta ambos terem o mesmo tamanho. uma sugestão que eu do é você debbugar seu codigo e ver o que está em cada variável.

Comment: Já descobri a solução: armazenar os resultados dos cálculos em lista, para depois chamá-las na elaboração do gráfico. assim que eu finalizar o código, postarei o resultado aqui. Grato!

Answer (score 1):

Para criar o `y` com o tamanho desejado basta criar uma listcomp usando o código abaixo, considerando que você está querendo travar o `y`como a média do atributo `SG`.

```
y = [df['SG'].mean() for k in range(0, len(df['SG']))]
```

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** Isso soluciona a questão do erro apresentado, mas do ponto de vista estatístico se deseja a correlação das variáveis, talvez não seja adequado fazer a correlação da variável com a média e sim com cada valor de `SG`.